# Replace string with new line - doubles up line spacing

Tags: javascript, replace

I am using a rich text editor to add content to the database. I have an edit post page, on which the content of the editor is populated by the existing content of the post.

I need to insert the content using JS due to the nature of the RTE. This feature is working fine,save for with the editors codeblocks. The line breaks are created in the codeblock using `\r` or `\n`. As I need to store the post content in JS once retrieving it, and because this created actual new lines in my output code it caused the variable to break up and not work, I removed all the line breaks.

When I add them back in, it seems to double up on the new lines and the spacing in the codeblocks alone (in the editor) gets messed up.

Here is the PHP snippet where the content is retrieved and manipulated:

```
$existingContent = addslashes( $post->content );
$existingContent = preg_replace( "/\n|\r/", "rwknbr", $existingContent );
```

Here is the Javascript - the slices are to remove some quotation marks that get added at the start and end:

```
let existingContent = "<?= $existingContent; ?>";
existingContent = existingContent.slice( 1 );
existingContent = existingContent.slice( 0, existingContent.length - 1 );
existingContent = existingContent.replace( /rwknbr/g, "\n" );

editor.children[ 0 ].innerHTML = existingContent;
```

Why are my line breaks being added back in twice, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `json_encode()` to convert a PHP value to a valid JavaScript literal, rather than using string replacements.

```
let existingContents = <?php echo json_encode($existingContent); ?>;
```

`json_encode()` will escape the newlines properly.